# Jquery stops working after page change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, onclick

I'm having this issue that I haven't had before. Once page changes to a different page it seems like the Jquery just stops working. I've looked around and the only promising solution seemed to be the $(window).load() solution but that didn't fix it either. I have no idea why this is happening. I've tested it by redirecting it to the very same page and nothing break then but once I go to a different page, it all stops working

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$("#goToNewPage").on('click', function()
    {
        alert("New Page 1");
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#NewPage");
    });

    $("#goToNewPage2").on('click', function()
    {
        alert("New Page 2");
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#NewPage2");
    });

    $("#goToLastPage").on('click', function()
    {
        alert("Last Page");
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#LastPage");
    });


});
```

HTML:

```
<body> 
<div data-role="page" id="main" class="background">
    <div id="logo">

    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="content">
        <div align="center">
            <p>MAIN</p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-footer-fixed">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="button" value="New Page" id="goToNewPage"/></li>
            <li><input type="button" value="New Page 2" id="goToNewPage2"/></li>
            <li><input type="button" value="Last Page" id="goToLastPage"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="NewPage" class="background">
    <div id="logo">

    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="content">
        <div align="center">
            <p>New Page 2</p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-footer-fixed">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="button" value="New Page" id="goToNewPage"/></li>
            <li><input type="button" value="New Page 2" id="goToNewPage2"/></li>
            <li><input type="button" value="Last Page" id="goToLastPage"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="NewPage2" class="background">
    <div id="logo">

    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="content">
        <div align="center">
            <p><b>New Page 2</b></p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="navbar" class="ui-footer-fixed">
        <ul>
            <li><input type="button" value="New Page" id="goToNewPage"/></li>
            <li><input type="button" value="New Page 2" id="goToNewPage2"/></li>
            <li><input type="button" value="Last Page" id="goToLastPage"/></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: id must be unique !

Comment: Take note that you're not navigating pages in the traditional sense, but using a mobile framework to simulate page navigation within a single page application. This is critical because you ***cannot*** have the same `id` on the same physical page...

Comment: So even between pages, the id's need to be unique? Is this new because I recently updated my jquery and have never had that problem before

Comment: War10ck so if the pages are in the same body, even though they are technically different pages, they are all in the same container hence they need different id's?

Comment: @user3618687 That's correct. The browser does not see this content as separate pages, but as separate sections of the same page document. The mobile framework is what simulates the _different_ pages that the user sees. This is not a new concept, however, I don't think the new version of jQuery would cause this either, though I cannot say for sure. They may have modified their selector logic.

Comment: I'm so stupid and it's not like I can fall back on the "I'm new to this" excuse either cause I'm not, it's either something new or just something I completely forgot. Either way thanks guys

Comment: Ensure that all ID attributes are unique. See HTML specification section 7.5.2 https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2